# When Using GZIP do I Need to Add Separate Mime-Types for Woff & Woff2 Font Files?

Tags: apache, gzip, mime-types, webfonts, woff

If I GZIP my site, when I add the code that covers the font file formats, will the `AddType x-font/woff .woff` line in the code below cover both `woff` and `woff2` font files, or will I need to add another line for woff2, which I'm guessing would be `AddType x-font/woff2 .woff2`

```
AddType x-font/otf .otf
AddType x-font/ttf .ttf
AddType x-font/eot .eot
AddType x-font/woff .woff
```

Thanks in advance for any answers

Em

Comment: Shouldn't you tag your question with 'mime-types' as well?

Comment: @Roadowl thanks. Have done this - I think'll I'll edit the question title as well.